# Distribute a script, but protect the password

Tags: python, gmail, password-protection

I have a script which will log into a STMP server (GMail's) to send an email notification. How can I do this without distributing the password in plain text?

Answer (score 1):

Have the script request the password when running.

Note, I wouldn't advise that it accept the password as a command line argument as this isn't very secure because it will be logged in the command history etc.

Comment: Not possible. It is non-interactive.

Comment: Does it have to be an email notification? Perhaps it could just ping a simple webservice to handle the notification instead? eg. it could just call www.amit.com/sendnotification?message=scriptExecuted

Comment: The email will contain information regarding monitoring a build job, etc. Now, the build nodes can vary, and hence the IP will also be included. Hence I felt that an email can be a good solution.

Comment: The web service you knock up to handle this can take all the details you need eg: www.amit.com/sendnotification?message=scriptExecuted&ip=127.0.0.1&job=test&duration=123456
When this web service is called it can just log the info or even send an email if you really want. No security problems here because the email credentials will be stored server-side.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the script look for an environmental variable for the password:

```
import os
password = os.environ['GMAIL_PASSWD']
```

Comment: And how would the password be protected when being stored in an environment variable?

Comment: It wouldn't, but the script would be safe to distribute without compromising the password, and would run non-interactively. If the question is "how do I allow people to log into *my* email account without compromising any authentication credentials," then I don't know the answer (it sounds hard)

Comment: I like this idea! It can help me distribute the script w/o the password.

Answer (score 0):

check if your provider offers an smtp server that doesn't require authentication and use that instead.